# How to find that subject, calculate the total marks of each student in all the other subjects C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

How to find that subject, calculate the total marks of each student in all the other subjects and then finally return the array of the total marks scored by each student.

Input Specification:

input1: An integer value X denoting number of students

input2: An integer value XY denoting number of subjects

input3: A 2-D integer array of size X'XY containing the marks of all students in each subject.

Output Specification:

Return an integer array of size X containing the total marks of each student afte deducting the score for that one subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: We will get the sum of each 'XY' subject for each student. After that we will compare all 'XY' sums and will get the minimum sum of 'XY' subject and index position of minimum sum of 'XY' subject from the input3.

After getting index position from input3. We will not consider that index position to add in total and we will avoid index position for all student.

Download working solution from GIT. Link in bottom.

Example 1:
INPUT
3 5

- 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,
- 2, 1, 3, 4, 1 ,
- 2, 5, 4, 1, 3

OUTPUT
14,9,13

Example 2:

INPUT
3 3

- 10 20 30
- 30 10 40
- 20 20 20

OUTPUT
40 70 40

Solution written in c#.

Download Solution Here: https://github.com/vaibhavsrivastava1991/StudentReport

If we can enhance solution, Most Welcome and Appreciated!!

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)